# Content Management - ASP.NET Recommendations

Tags: asp.net, sql, content-management

Build vs. Buy...  We've all been down this road...  It seems like content management solutions need to be a tool that you keep inside the toolbox for some quick wins and they are only getting better.  I could certainly look at building one, but by the time you get all the bells and whistles in there, it would have been cheaper to get one off the shelf...

I've searched [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=content+management) for some recommendations, but it appears that there really haven't been any highly rated ideas for ASP.NET implementations.

Don't get me wrong, PHP and mySQL certainly have their place, but there are some instances where you really have to stick with ASP.NET and SQL Server implementations due to other limitations.  Both [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) and [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/) seem pretty cool, but I won't be able to get these setup and installed in the environments I have to work with.

What are the best ASP.NET CMS solutions out there?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd try a slightly more targeted search:

> [[asp.net] "content management"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[asp.net]+%22content+management%22)

Filter it to just questions tagged "asp.net", and ensure that you're searching for the phrase Content Management, rather than the two words.

A lot of it comes down to your definition of "Content Management" really. I've spent the last 5 years working professionally with things like Microsoft's CMS, and recently a bit of MOSS Web Content Management, and before that on two or three bespoke CMS that we'd written for a publishing house, so I consider a CMS to be a complete site building tools, focused around publishing multiple types and styles of content.

On the opensource/free/cheap side I've looked at few recently and found the following:

- [N2 CMS](http://www.n2cms.com) - This is what I've settled on using, mainly because they have a working MVC implementation, and I want to learn that, but it's also the closest I've found to my definition of a CMS
- [Umbraco](http://www.umbraco.net/) - Close second, let down by the lack of MVCness at the time.
- [Graffiti CMS](http://graffiticms.com/) - Didn't really cut it with me as a CMS, more of a glorified blogging engine
- [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) - VB, and I work in C#. Great if what you really want is a portal however.

Just my thoughts to back up the usual bland lists.

Comment: Good call on the targeted search...  I assume the [asp.net] is a tag search?

Comment: Yep, if you want to search explicitly on tags, wrap them in [].

Also, I meant to add, I've looked at Umbraco, but not used it, a friend however has used both that and N2, and reported back that N2 was more fully featured.

Comment: +1 for N2.  It has being actively developed and the developer gives good feedback on the forum.  It doesn't have everything you might need yet, but it is flexible enough to give you *only* the functionality you need.

Comment: Composite C1 is a new one for the list: http://compositec1.codeplex.com/

Comment: @mawtex - I've not looked at that one, but could possibly go and check it out (along with the now officially released "Orchard" option from MS) when I get a moment. The list wasn't meant to be exhaustive (clearly it's not) but more "Here's what I looked at, and why I did/didn't chose to use it".

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check out [Umbraco](http://www.umbraco.net/) - completely written in C#/.NET, with a very powerful programming API (using lots of XSLT for transformations).

They offer both a free community edition as well as commercial versions.

Marc

Comment: Interesting...  Don't know if I like the price tag, but that is just because I'm cheap.

Comment: Hmm.... can't seem to find any mention on their normal website - but they have a free, open-source community version, too - check out: http://umbraco.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft has released "Orchard"...  This looks to be a solid CMS implementation on the ASP.NET MVC platform.

http://orchard.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

I saw [an article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/02/437220.aspx) (written by [ScottGu](http://www.axcms.net/)) about a cms named [axcms](http://www.axcms.net/). You can try it.

Comment: Not sure why you were down voted...  http://www.axcms.net/en_axcms_home.AxCMS?ActiveID=1848 seems like a good rec.

Answer (score 2):

My own favourite is [Tridion](http://www.sdltridion.com), which can be used for either .NET or Java-based sites. It's not free, though, if that's what you're looking for.

[Composite](http://www.composite.net/) may also be interesting - also not free, but it has a possibility of a trial period.

Comment: "It's not free, though" now there's an understatement ;) It's an enterprise content management system, with big features for admins (and not just content admins).

Comment: Tridion has some nice features, but the price...

Comment: It's about total cost of ownership, so "It's not free" is less of an understatement than a bare statement of fact. The free offerings aren't free either. For a typical Tridion implementation, the license fee is a small proportion of the overall cost. Most web sites start with bespoke requirements, so whatever tool you use, free or otherwise, you will have costs.

Answer (score 1):

[DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com) is probably the most popular and has lots of plug-ins & documentation.
It's written in VB.NET though :(

Comment: I agree and god help you if something breaks. :(

Comment: +1 to Kev...  DNN has its perks, but can be a royal pain in the...

Answer (score 1):

I have been using DotNetNuke recently and highly recommend it.  It was very easy to install, especially from the Web Platform Installer (from Microsoft) and also really easy to customize.

My clients ended up buying a skin, but I found it really easy to build a skin myself and customize the purchased skin as well.  Try searching for Free XHTML DotNetNuke skins.

It was also really easy to build new modules as well!  I've written four so far - in C# - and it was very easy.

The actual DNN source was written in VB.NET with lots of HTML tables.  It is definitely **not** anywhere near what most people consider best practices, but it does work quite well.  It's one of those software projects where it works really good and then you look behind the scenes and you regret you did that.

I once evaluated it, and didn't get past the source because it was VB.NET.  I regret that now - this last project went really well for me.  So, I highly recommend it.  It's not like it will cost you anything but the time you spent evaluating.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming to this discussion a few years late, but I'll pitch in some thoughts from the procurement side for prosperity. The landscape changes, but for commercial CMS, I'd look at the vendors recommended by research firms. For open source solutions, I'd look for a large active community, documentation, and a support model you could live with.

We started research for a CMS in 2008 with online searches and the ultimate CMS list http://www.cmsmatrix.org/. (boggles the mind how many "CMS's" are out there)

We ended up looking at ".NET-friendly" CMS recommended by Gartner and Forrester. Gartner's "Magic Quadrant" of leaders/challengers and niche/visionaries and Forrester's "Wave" point out both feature sets as well as marketplace and vendor roadmap.

A good request for proposal (RFP) or comparison tip isn't to ask "do you feature X?" but to compare and see which solution does it *better*.

At the time, Kentico and Sitefinity were on our evaluation list as .NET-friendly. We also considered DotNetNuke, though there was a mild objection to "becoming DNN programmers" rather than staying mainly .NET (I'm sure there's a mis-perception in there, no offense).

We ended up comparing RedDot and Tridion and found Tridion to be a better fit for us because of its .NET API and flexibility.

Answer (score -1):

You could try these:

- http://rainbowportal.net/
- http://www.ektron.com/
- http://www.joomla.org/
- http://www.opensourcecms.com/

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try to review these later.