# Need ASP.NET CMS like MODx PHP one

Tags: php, asp.net, content-management-system, modx

When I need to develop a solution using a CMS I recommend to my clients to use MODx, flexible to me as developer and easy to user for content managers. This time my client has introduce a requirement: the solution should be using ASP.NET. The problem is that in my research I couldn't  find an equivalent ASP.NET CMS to MODx (http://modxcms.com). I gave a look to DotNetNuke but is not that I'm looking for, so complex.

I'll appreciate anybody help.

Best regards,
Lester

Comment: I know this is old, but did you ever find anything close to Modx. I really liked that and wish I could find an asp.net mvc that was open source and rolled like modx.

Comment: kooboo (http://www.kooboo.com) should be an alternative. It's ASP.NET MVC and in many aspects is similar to MODx. Try it out to see if fits your expectations.

Answer (score 3):

I am mainly an asp.net developer but recently due to low resourses at work I've helped out with a few modx and drupal sites.

I didn't take to Drupal at all but I love modx, really love. IMO It just makes so much sense to a developer.

I've had a look around the asp.net market and tried a few but don't have anything conclusive yet. I really like the modx templating system and that's where most other CMS's fall down in my opinion.

I had some joy with [mojoportal](http://www.mojoportal.com/) although I haven't been able to devote as much time to it as I would like yet to see if it is a suitable replacement.

Comment: I've also heard good things about n2cms (http://n2cms.com/) but haven't had time to look at it yet.

Comment: I found that I was looking for: kooboo (www.kooboo.com). Simple to use and powerful for developers at same time. Based in ASP.NET MVC, has a lovely template management, like MODx. I strongly recommend it as ASP.NET alternative of MODx. There are some interesting features that worth.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of questions relating to ASP.NET based CMS's here already:

1. [Content Management ASP.NET Recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639316/content-management-asp-net-recommendations/640413#640413)
2. [ASP.NET CMS search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net+cms)

I hope those help you - personally, I'd recommend that you take a look at [N2 CMS](http://n2cms.com), as I've been using it for a couple of sites, and found it to be a joy to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not really sure how complex you want your CMS, but I know of two:

1. Sitecore CMS - what we use, very powerful with it's own API, easy to add custom content
2. Sitefinity by Telerik - not as complex, but very easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

I am not too familiar with the PHP CMSs, but I can speak to Sitefinity CMS.

Sitefinity is a very developer friendly CMS platform. It is a CMS for ASP.NET that doesn't "reivent the wheel" or significantly change the way ASP.NET works. If you're an ASP.NET developer (or have any ASP.NET experience), Sitefinity will be very familiar. For instance:

- Themes = MasterPages
- Modules = UserControls
- Config = Web.Config

For developers, it's also like "one big API." The APIs enable you to do everything from create pages to edit content to modify and extend the Sitefinity admin. In fact, there was a webinar today talking about the APIs. You can probably find the link to the recorded version later here, though:

[Sitefinity API Tips & Tricks Webinar](http://sitefinitywatch.com/blog/09-08-17/Webinar_this_Week_Sitefinity_API_Tips_amp_Tricks.aspx)

Finally, for your end users / clients, the Sitefinity tools are very friendly. Sitefintiy ships with the Telerik RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX (leading UI components for the web), so you get great tools to work with that your users can easily use.

Oh- and Sitefinity is *very* affordable compared to most other commercial .NET CMSs. It's usually $1000's of dollars less than some of the other Enterprise-grade CMSs it competes with.

Hope that helps. More details and demos (of course) are available on [Sitefinity.com](http://www.sitefinity.com).

Answer (score 0):

I would point at [Umbraco](http://umbraco.org) which should have a very clean seperation between code/ui. Modules for this can be found on Codeplex